# not able to create directory using dfs in hadoop

Tags: java, android, apache, ubuntu, hadoop

I'm trying to create a folder using the below command

```
manoj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hadoop dfs -mkdir /tmp
```

I am encountering, however, the following error:

```
mkdir: unknown host: hadoop
```

I have posted the log file, and would appreciate some assistance. I have installed single-node on hadoop. It looks like java unknownhostexception error. Please let me know what to do to correct this.

```
manoj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ cat hadoop-manoj-datanode-ubuntu.log
2014-10-05 13:08:30,621 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ubuntu/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1479473; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Mon May  6 06:59:37 UTC 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_65
************************************************************/
2014-10-05 13:08:32,449 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2014-10-05 13:08:32,514 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2014-10-05 13:08:32,519 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2014-10-05 13:08:32,519 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2014-10-05 13:08:34,173 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2014-10-05 13:08:34,191 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2014-10-05 13:08:36,439 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: hadoop
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1087)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1798)

2014-10-05 13:08:36,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Are you looking for the Hadoop fs shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a configuration problems.
I'm assuming you use a recent version of Hadoop - if that is the case, you should use the `hdfs` command instead. So try `bin/hdfs dfs -ls` to see if any of your fs commands work.
I'm guessing they won't work. In that case you should check your core-site.xml for the HDFS settings (`fs.defaultFS`).

Comment: manoj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp1

bash: bin/hdfs: No such file or directory

manoj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp1

No command 'hdfs' found, did you mean:

 Command 'hdfls' from package 'hdf4-tools' (universe)

 Command 'hfs' from package 'hfsutils-tcltk' (universe)

hdfs: command not found

Answer (score 0):

go to $HADOOP_HOME and try `$bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp`

Comment: manoj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp1
mkdir: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:10001 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: seems you didn't start hdfs or your Namenode is not running. make sure you have HDFS running `$bin/start-all.sh`. once it ran, use jps command to chechk the process NameNode, DataNode

Comment: I made some changes in /etc/hosts file and started all services,now hadoop command is working fine.But when I check the process using jps,I see job tracker and tasktracker are stopping immediately after running.So I find only below processes.What happened to job tracker and task tracker or is this normal??,Please let me know.
manoj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/$ jps
3599 DataNode
4359 Jps
3460 NameNode
3737 SecondaryNameNode

Comment: job tracker and task tracker are related to mapreduce. if you do  start-mapred.sh or start-all.sh then those process shows when you do jps. I think you have started only hdfs

Comment: yes,I can see job tracker and task tracker when I start-all.sh, but they are stopping automatically.That's my concern.